# What is the default behavior of index_col in Pandas' read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

In the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#column-and-index-locations-and-names), for the function `read_csv`, I'm trying to understand what the following explanation about the behavior of the function is when `index_col` is set to its default value, `None`:

> The default value of None instructs pandas to guess. If the number of
> fields in the column header row is equal to the number of fields in
> the body of the data file, then a default index is used. If it is
> larger, then the first columns are used as index so that the remaining
> number of fields in the body are equal to the number of fields in the
> header.
>
> The first row after the header is used to determine the number of
> columns, which will go into the index. If the subsequent rows contain
> less columns than the first row, they are filled with NaN.

So I came up with the following toy example:

```
with open("io_tools_example_index.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("pandas, koalas, lizards, kangaroos\n1,2,3\n4,5,6")
```

When I do `pd.read_csv("io_tools_example_index.txt")`, I get:

[image]

whereas based on their explanation, I would have expected Pandas to use the `pandas` column as the index since the number of fields in the column header is larger than the number of fields in the remaining lines. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous, but the "it" in "If it is larger" refers to the number of fields in the body of the data file rather than number of column header fields. If you had a CSV file named `foo2.csv` with the contents

```
pandas, koalas
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

then "1" and "4" would be used as the indices of the rows in the body, so running `pd.read_csv("foo2.csv")` would get you this:

```
   pandas   koalas
1       2        3
4       5        6
```